# Deployed a website in React using Netlify, but I get a blank page

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

I was trying to deploy a project I made in ReactJS - a tetris game to be exact - and I am coming up with the following error:

[image]
On a different stack-overflow post, I read that most likely this is happening because
Most likely there is a reference to manifest.json somewhere in the project, while the file/resource itself does not exist and that I should look for link tags containing `rel=manifest`.

So I went into my index.html folder and removed the following:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

So after making the changes and updating my code, I pushed to Netlify (netlify deploy, netlify open) and I keep getting the same error.  Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? The project runs perfectly on localhost.

EDIT: adding Network tab image
[image]

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the Network tab, from the start? Are other requests (like index.html itself) fetched without issues?

Comment: Just added the image, @yuriy636

Comment: I took a peak into the source code and it looks like the HTML is the template (you can see the _This HTML file is a template_ text inside). This means that you are not serving the built app, which should be the content generated by `npm run build`. You might need to look for a Create React App & Netlify specific tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove `manifest.json` file. What you need to do is simply connect source code to the version control.

You need to add `_redirects` file to the **public** folder. (no extension for this file). add this line to it.

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

From this, we hope to show components accordingly whenever link updates with components.

Then follow the below steps to host your site easily,

1. Add your source code to the Bitbucket repository. (connect your local folder to repo)
2. If you have build remove that folder.
3. Go to Netlify and link your Bitbucket repository and desired domain.
4. That's it! Whenever you push the new version to the master branch it will auto-deploy. (No need to build anymore! - make sure to enabled auto-deploy settings to the master branch)

Just use these tools easily. Don't use a lengthy way and make things hard.

Comment: just link it to netlify !